# Finding top features with SGD classifier & GridsearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

```
# Implementing Linear_SGD classifier
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000)
Cs = [0.0001,0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]
tuned_parameters = [{'alpha': Cs}]
model = GridSearchCV(clf, tuned_parameters, scoring = 'accuracy', cv=2)
model.fit(x_train, Y_train)
```

how to find the top important features from the below code as it is showing error feature_count_.

here my vectorizer is BOW and classifier is SGDclassifier with hinge loss

```
def important_features(vectorizer,classifier,n=20):
    class_labels = classifier.classes_
    feature_names =vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.feature_count_[0], 
    feature_names),reverse=True)[:n]
    topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.feature_count_[1], 
    feature_names),reverse=True)[:n]
    print("Important words in negative reviews")
```

I tried with the above code but it is showing error as

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-093048fb461e> in <module>()
----> 1 important_features(Timesort_X_vec,model)

<ipython-input-75-10b9d6ee3f81> in important_features(vectorizer, 
classifier, n)
  2     class_labels = classifier.classes_
  3     feature_names =vectorizer.get_feature_names()
   ----> 4     topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.feature_count_[0], 
feature_names),reverse=True)[:n]
  5     topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.feature_count_[1], 
feature_names),reverse=True)[:n]
  6     print("Important words in negative reviews")

 AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'feature_count_'.
```

As i am newbie to programming please help me out with your answers. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the SGDClassifier which you are using does not have a `feature_count_` attribute (check the available attributes in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier  

X = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]]
y = [0, 1]
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter=5)
clf.fit(X, y) 

clf.feature_count_
[...]
AttributeError: 'SGDClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_count_'
```

Initially I thought that the problem was in that you were using a GridSearchCV object, but this is not the case, since the line `class_labels = classifier.classes_` inside your function does not raise any error; and although from the docs it seems that SGDClassifier does not even have a `classes_` attribute, in practice it turns out it indeed has:

```
clf.classes_
# array([0, 1])
```

The only classifiers in scikit-learn I am aware to include a `feature_count_` attribute are [BernoulliNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html), [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html), and [ComplementNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.ComplementNB.html), all of the Naive Bayes family, although I am not quite sure it can be used as you intend to use it here...